# background button press detection

Tags: java, android, service, background

I am trying to build an android app which detects button pressed on a background and plays a sound or something. For demo, I am trying to add this method

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    final MediaPlayer abc = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.abc);
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
        abc.start();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

to this class

```
public class RSSPullService extends IntentService{
    public RSSPullService(){
        super("Nevermind me");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

    }
}
```

Is there something that can be helpful? I am new to android development and Java.

Answer (score 0):

In touch android mobile phones there is not any keyboard hardware. So please specify which button you want to get pressed?

Edited:

Add the following permission in Manifest fie:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PREVENT_POWER_KEY" />
```

and override following methods:

```
//To capture any short click of button
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
    // this is method which detect press even of button
    event.startTracking(); // Needed to track long presses
    return true;
}
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


//To capture long press of power button
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
    // Here we can detect long press of power button
    return true;
}
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Power button pressed 3-4 times to be more specific.

Comment: Sorry for asking simple thing, but can you help me run onKeyDown() on background that is when app is minimized or not running?